# Tcl: how to print one set

Tags: tcl

My file to be parsed is like this

```
Name : John
Pin : 5400
Age : 40
Place: Korea
Amount : 4000
Name : Peter
Pin : 6700
Age : 10
Place : Japan
Amount : 3600
```

My tcl code is

```
set start "Name"
set pn "Pin"
set ag "Age"
set ag_cutoff 15
set amnt "Amount"
foreach line [split $content "\n"] {
   if {[regexp $start $line]} {
      set count 1
      set l1 $line
   }
   if {[regexp $pn $line] && $count ==1} {
       set pin_val [lindex $line 2]
       set l2 $line
   }
   if {[regexp $ag $line] && $count ==1} {
      set ag [lindex $line 2]
      if { $ag > $ag_cutoff} {
          set rep_taken 1
          set l3 $line
      }
      if {[regexp $amnt $line] && $count ==1 && $rep_taken == 1} {
          set age_val [lindex $line 2]
          puts $op1 "$ag $age_val "
          puts $op2 "$l1\n$l2\n$l3\n"
      }
```

This code is fine for plots.

However, I also want to o/p a file with complete set where $ag>$ag_cutoff.
Now with puts $op3 "$l1\n$l2\n$l3\n" ---> Able to print to a file. But how to print line Place which is not evaluated. Any better way to accomplish this.

```
Name : John
Pin : 5400
Age : 40
Place : Korea
Amount : 4000
```

Comment: So, a `Name :` line marks the start of each record?

Comment: yes and it ends at Amount.

Comment: Able to print lines but not complete set by puts $op2 "$l1\n$l2\n$l3\n".  But still not able to print complete set including Place : Korea

Comment: You need a blank between Place and : to output Korea.

Comment: @PeterLewerin did not understand your point. My doubt is how to print lines which are not evaluated in a set. should I do dummy regexp for Place or any other row as well.

Comment: You have to have the fields in memory to be able to output them, so if you want to do it the way you are doing it, I can't see that you can avoid adding code recognizing and storing them. This is a lot more complicated than it needs to be, however.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot simpler to let the parsing loop just create a dictionary (this replaces your code above):

```
set data {}
set count 0
foreach line [split $content \n] {
    if {[lindex $line 0] eq "Name"} {
        incr count
    }
    dict set data $count [lindex $line 0] [lindex $line 2]
}
```

This will blow up if the first line doesn't start with "Name", or if there is a missing blank between a colon and a word, and also if a value consists of several words. All of these are easy to fix.

Here, for instance, is an expanded version that takes care of the last two problems, should they occur:

```
set data {}
set count 0
foreach line [split $content \n] {
    set keyword [string trimright [lindex $line 0] :]
    set value [string trimleft [lrange $line 1 end] {: }]
    if {$keyword eq "Name"} {
        incr count
    }
    dict set data $count $keyword $value
}
```

When all records are stored, one can output selected records using dictionary iteration:

```
set ag_cutoff 15
dict for {count record} $data {
    if {[dict get $record Age] > $ag_cutoff} {
        dict for {k v} $record {
            puts "$k : $v"
        }
    }
}
```

This also means that you can keep adding fields to the records, and the code will still work without change.

**Precautions**

If the data in `content` has empty lines at the beginning or end, or between some lines, these methods won't work. A simple way to guard against empty or blank lines at the beginning or the end is to replace

```
foreach line [split $content \n] {
```

with

```
foreach line [split [string trim $content] \n] {
```

If empty / blank lines may occur within the data, one can use this to skip them:

```
foreach line [split $content \n] {
    if {[string is space $line]} continue
```

If one is 100% sure that all data is in proper list form, it is possible (but a bit code-smelly) to use list commands like `lindex` on it directly. If one is less sure, or if one wants to be more correct, one should convert each line to a list before working on it:

```
foreach line [split $content \n] {
    set line [split $line]
```

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Careful about using `lindex` on the string `$line`. You should throw a `split` into the loop

Comment: @glennjackman: since the original code assumed that the file data was "list safe", I took the liberty of letting my code assume the same thing.